# While block with try catch and scanner. How to clear the scanner?

Tags: java

I know that my code is not really proper in case of "clear coding" but it was made just to test some features.

So here's the code:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;
int index = 0;
boolean flag = true;
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while(flag) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Type the first nubmer: ");
        x = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        flag = false;
        break;
    }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Type a proper number you idiot!");
        flag = true;
    }

}
flag = true;

while(flag) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Type the second nubmer: ");
        y = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        if(y == 0) {
            System.out.println("Can't divide by 0!");
            continue;
        }
        flag = false;
        break;
    }catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Type a proper number you idiot!");
        flag = true;
    }
}
System.out.println("The result is: " + x/y);
```

Once the InputMismatchException occurs the output is infinite with:

```
Type a proper number you idiot!
Type the second nubmer: 
Type a proper number you idiot!
```

And so on.

What it made to work fine was change

```
x = scanner.nextInt();
y = scanner.nextInt();
```

to:

```
x = Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
y = Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
```

So i need to make new instance of the Scanner with every loop. Here's the question - how to clear the scanner to make it work fine without need of making new instance every time?

Comment: many dupes here on the site, please attempt to do some research before posting.

Comment: Are you reading anything besides `int`(s) in your code? If not, you do not need all of those `nextLine()` calls.

Comment: No, nothing else is being read. But whether the nextLine() method is called or not, the output is still the same.

Aomine, i have made a research. But everyone says that if i want to "clear" the scanner i need to call scanner.nextLine(). But here it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that you don't give time for the user to give an input if it's an error. the line `scanner.nextLine()` does this, and should be a fix to your code. If you have any questions, just ask.

```
  int x = 0;
    int y = 0;
    int index = 0;
    boolean flag = true;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(flag) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Type the first nubmer: ");
            x = scanner.nextInt();
            flag = false;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Type a proper number you idiot!");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }

    }
    flag = true;

    while(flag) {
        try {
            System.out.println("Type the second nubmer: ");
            y = scanner.nextInt();
            if(y == 0) {
                System.out.println("Can't divide by 0!");
                continue;
            }
            flag = false;
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Type a proper number you idiot!");
            scanner.nextLine();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The result is: " + x/y);
```